# Send http request from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to send http request to a web api from posgresql databse? I will create a trigger and it will post a requet to an http api when a new record created.

Comment: There is no built-in method for doing that. And doing that in a triggers seems like a bad idea as well.

Comment: You can write a PL/PerlU or PL/Python function that does such things, but I would not do that in a trigger.

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/movEAX/d128a9602cf93e3dba2e): push the event to a ZMQ socket and then write a listener in any language which supports ZMQ (pretty much any language). And that listener will send the request to the API.

Comment: I never used it so far but there is a foreign data wrapper for WWW - https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw - check it. To me it looks like something you could use.

Comment: @JosMac Can I post it to msmq or rabbitmq like this?

Comment: Could you please add example(s) of post request(s) for them into your original question?